# Jenkins email-ext plugin - Use scriptler to set msg sender email address

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

I have a groovy script under $JENKINS_HOME/email-templates named sender_email_address.groovy which has the following code

```
<%
StringBuilder builderEmail = new StringBuilder()
builderEmail.append("${build.buildVariables.get('BUILD_USER')}")
builderEmail.append("@collective.com")
def sender_email = builderEmail.toString()
%>
${sender_email}
```

I am trying to set the email sender address from the pre-send script of email-ext plugin. Here is the code which does that:

```
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType
import javax.mail.Address
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage

def senderAddress = ${SCRIPT, script="sender_email_address.groovy"}
listener.logger("Sender address = " + senderAddress)
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderAddress))
```

I get the following error:

```
def senderAddress = Error in script or template: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.
<%
^
```

I am trying to set the from address of the email being sent to be the user who is logged in. I have the access to ${BUILD_USER} value available. But if I directly use it in the pre-send script as shown below

```
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("${BUILD_USER}")
```

the script directly replaces the ${BUILD_USER} token with the email address in the script itself. This defeats the purpose of tokenizing it since the next time I log in with a different user, the token isn't available to be replaced. Is there a way I can achieve it elsewhere just retaining the token ${BUILD_USER}?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ${SCRIPT} token with the "script" parameter, you don't need the <% %> like you do for a template. So, your code should be something like this:

```
StringBuilder builderEmail = new StringBuilder()
builderEmail.append("${build.buildVariables.get('BUILD_USER')}")
builderEmail.append("@collective.com")
builderEmail.toString()
```